# Do I need a special thermostat to take advantage of a modulating gas valve?

Tags: thermostat, furnace, gas, forced-air

I just had a high efficiency condensing gas furnace installed. I feel like it was done poorly, but I'm not sure. Some questions I'm wondering about are:

1. Do furnaces need to be level? It is visibly tilted, but at least it's tilted so the water drain is lower.
2. Does the vent pipe need to be a certain distance from any windows? Mine is almost touching a window.
3. Do I need a special thermostat to take advantage of a modulating gas valve? They gave me a thermostat that has 1 or 2 heating stages (1H or 2H). The gas valve has 60 settings (40-100%), but I didn't see any thermostats with more than 4 or 5 stages of heating.

Furnace model: **Trane XC95m**.

Thermostat: **Honeywell T6 Pro WiFi**

Comment: Nathan, welcome. Please [take the tour](https://diy.stackexchange.com/tour) to learn what makes a good question and what you're expected to do with it. You're asking several distinct questions here that should be separated.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like a basic setup. I will set high efficiency furnaces at a slight angle to help drainage of the condensate. Some systems have pans inside that are already sloped, and in that case they can be level.

The vent and supplies can touch walls and windows. When retrofitting from an open combustion to closed where new supply and exhaust vents are required it can be difficult to make things look nice, but they need to have the correct slope to drain condensate back or there will be problems later.

As far as thermostats they should have offered you different models, the more bells and whistles in a thermostat the more they cost. If the job was a contract price you probably got a low to mid level thermostat.

Did you get a bad job? Not from the questions you are asking. Things that indicate below-standard work are if the duct work is not sealed and the condensate doesn't drain properly.

Comment: Thanks Ed, that makes me feel better. Sounds like the install is fine then.

Comment: I believe it sounds ok photos are always helpful but even then it can look sketchy because it was a retrofit and be a really good job. I have found jobs that looked ok but we're not properly sealed from the trunk ducts to the furnace (big leaks). So with your concerns listed it sounds ok.

Answer (score -1):

FWIW if the window is operable there are code requirements for offset to exhaust gases (typ. 3' I believe but can be more). That said, the window is probably (hopefully!) not open when the furnace is running, so in reality not likely a health-and-safety issue